# Can speed change the Photoelectric affect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, optics, energy

Say I have an 849nm light source and a metal plate made of a certain element. The minimum energy required to eject electrons from the surface of this element is the photoelectric work function. Say the threshold for this material corresponds to a wavelength of 850 nm. According to theory and experimental testing none of the photons, no matter the intensity can eject electrons from this material.

Now separate the light source and the metal plate by a very large distance and start moving them toward each other at a slow speed.

My questions:
(1) Is there a certain speed that the two can reach where electrons do begin to eject?
(2) if so, is there a name for this experiment and can you direct me to it? Thanks

Comment: The light will be subject to doppler shift. So yes, there is a velocity at which the light will be able to excite electrons in the material

Comment: @planetmaker (1) Is there a certain speed?  (2) Is there an experiment where this has been tested?

Comment: The one type of spectroscopy that uses a shift like this is [Mössbauer spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ssbauer_spectroscopy) Perhaps someone else can thing of another

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to bounce the light off a fast- moving mirror.  "Fast" is  $ v = c(850-849)/(2 \times 849)$ or faster.  It would be a fun test of special relativity, but the outcome is not in doubt: the photon energies would increase as expected as $v$ increases, and the photoelectric effect would show it nicely.

Comment: That’s like 194,000 mph. Has anyone ever done it?

Comment: Do it with multiple bounces, and it could get down to an achievable speed.  Might be yet easier to try to bounce the photons off a nonrelativistic electron beam.  But however it's done, it amounts to illuminating the plate with a slightly higher frequency, shorter wavelength beam which could be obtained in a myriad of other, easier, ways.  The photons won't be different due to the way they are formed.

Comment: Now I’m really curious. I know I asked the question but I really assumed the experiment had been done somewhere. Does anyone know?